# Binary search given slightly inaccurate results

Tags: c++, c++11, search, binary-search

The problem I am trying to solve is the following: I get **N** rectangular paper strips with 1cm width and length **C**. I need to cut the strips at a height where the sum of the areas of the cut strip is equal to **A**. You can see an example bellow for which **N** = 5, the strips are of length, 5,3,6,2 and 3 cm and **A** = 3cm where the cut is made at 4cm.

[image: URI online judge]

Note that I'm looking here for the red area.

The input is given as follows. The first line in each case begins with two integers **N** (1 ≤ **N** ≤ 10^5) and **A** (1 ≤ **A** ≤ 10^9) representing respectively the number of strips and the expected resulting area. The next line contains N integers, representing the length C_i (1 <= C_i <= 10^4) of each strip.
The input ends with **A** = **C** = 0, which should not be processed.

For each test case, output a single line, the height **H** of the cut that must be done so that the sum of the area of the cut strips is equal to **A** cm². Print the answer with 4 decimal places. Output ":D" if no cutting is required, or "-.-" if it’s impossible.

This problem can be found [here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1912)

My idea for solving this problem was to use a binary search where I pick a height in the middle of the strips and make it larger or smaller depending on whether my cut was too high or too low. My implementation of the problem is given bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;  // Vector that holds paper heights
    int n;          // Number of papers
    double h,       // Height of the cut
           sum,     // Area sum
           min_n,   // Minimum height for cut to happen
           max_n,   // Maximum height for cut to happen
           a;       // Desired final area

    // Set desired output
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4);

    /* Get number of papers and desired area,
       terminates if N = A = 0
    */
    while(cin >> n >> a && (n||a)){
        v.resize(n); // Resize vector to fit all papers
        // Get all paper sizes
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin >> v[i];
        }
        /* Sort the vector in decreasing order to
           simplify the search
        */
        sort(v.begin(),v.end(),greater<int>());
        max_n = v[0]; // Largest possible cut is at the height of the largest paper
        min_n = 0; // Smallest possible cut is at the base with height 0

        // Iterate until answer is found
        while(true){
            // Initialize cut height as the average of smallest and largest cut sizes
            h = (min_n + max_n)/2;

            /* The area sum is equal to the sum of the areas of each cut, which is
               given by the height of the paper minus the cut height. If the cut is
               higher than the paper, the cut has area 0.
            */
            sum = 0;
            // Using mascoj sugenstion, a few changes were added
            int s; // Temporary variable to hold number of time h is subtracted
            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
                if(v[i] <= h) break; // From here onward cut area is 0 and there is no point adding
                sum += v[i]; // Removed the subtraction inside of the for loop
                s++; // Count how many paper strips were used
            }
            sum -= h*s // Subtracts the area cut from the s paper strips

            // If the error is smaller than the significant value, cut height is printed
            if(std::abs(sum-a) < 1e-5){
                // If no cut is needed print :D else print cut height
                (h < 1e-4 ? cout << ":D" << endl : cout << h << endl);
                break;
            }
            // If max_n is "equal" to min_n and no answer was found, there is no answer
            else if(max_n - min_n < 1e-7){
                cout << "-.-" << endl;
                break;
            }
            // Reduces search interval
            sum < a ? max_n = h : min_n = h;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, after submitting my answer I keep getting a 10% error. The website has a tool for comparing the output of you program with the expected output so I ran a test file with over 1000 randomly generated test cases and when I compared both I got a rounding error on the 4th decimal case, unfortunately, I don't have the file nor the script to generate test cases for me anymore. I tried changing the acceptable error to a smaller one but that didn't work. I can't seem to find the error, does any of you have an idea of what is happening?

**ps: Although the problem doesn't say on the description, you can get cuts with fractions as heights**

Comment: Try replacing `abs` with `std::abs` to make sure you don't accidentally call `int abs(int)` from `cstdlib`.

Comment: Thanks bud but still not the case :/

Comment: _"Print the answer with 4 decimal places"_ can mean either rounding or truncation. So maybe try calling [`std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) before you print the values.

Comment: A style suggestion: eliminate the `break` from the for loop and move the condition into the loop itself instead. `for (i=0; i<n && v[i]>h; i++)`

Comment: You say you're getting a 10% error, but then you also say it's an error in the 4th decimal place which would be 0.01%. Which is it?

Comment: @MarkRansom when they test it they do with 10 secret test cases and I'm missing one of them hence 10%. They also have a tool that will give you the right answer for the test cases that you do, from which I generated 1000 random test cases and when I compare with their answer, since the solution must be printed to 4 decimal places, in about  0.3% of them I'm off by 0.0001

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Is the answer supposed to be truncated or rounded? Was your answer always too high or too low?

Comment: Rounded, sometimes it is +0.0001 and sometimes -0.0001

Answer (score 0):

Might be your problem, maybe not: This line is exacerbating floating point error: `sum += v[i]-h;`

Floating points are only so accurate and compounding this error over a larger summation adds up. I would try using multiplication on `h` and subtracting that from the total sum of applicable lengths. Should be well within the range of the double precision format so I wouldn't worry about overrunning the format.

Comment: It's still not the case, I just modified the code with your suggestion but the 10% error still there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your algorithm but I think that can be done a lot simpler using a map instead a vector.

In the following example the map `mp` memorize how much (the value) strips are of a given lenght (the key).

An advantage of the map is ordered.

Next you can see how much you have to save (not to cat) and calculate the level of the cut starting from zero, adding 1 when appropriate and adding a fraction when neccessary.

Hope the following example can help

```
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   int                         n;
   int                         n2;
   int                         v;
   int                         cut;
   int                         a;
   std::map<int, std::size_t>  mp;
   long long int               sum;
   long long int               ts;


   std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);

   while( (std::cin >> n >> a) && ( n || a ) )
    {
      mp.clear();

      n2  = 0;
      sum = 0LL;

      for ( auto i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
       {
         std::cin >> v;

         if ( v > 0 )
          {
            sum += v;

            ++mp[v];
            ++n2;
          }
       }

      // mp is a map, so the values are ordered

      // ts is "to save"; sum of lenghts minus a
      ts  = sum - a;

      // cut level
      cut = 0;

      // while we can add a full cm to the cut level
      while ( (ts > 0LL) && (n2 > 0) && (ts >= n2) )
       {
         ++cut;

         ts -= n2;

         if ( cut >= mp.cbegin()->first )
          {
            n2 -= mp.cbegin()->second;

            mp.erase(mp.cbegin());
          }
       }

      if ( (ts == 0LL) && (cut == 0) )
         std::cout << ":D" << std::endl; // no cut required (?)
      else if ( n2 == 0 )
         std::cout << "-.-" << std::endl; // impossible (?)
      else
         std::cout << (cut + double(ts) / n2) << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

p.s.: observe that `a` is defined as an integer in the page that you link.

Comment: I can't use map though, nothing stops me from having 2 or more papers with the same length

Comment: @JoãoAreias - I've used maps precisely because you can have papers with the same length: the key is the length and the value is the number of papers with that length. If you prefer, you can use a multiset but I think that a map is better.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what is happening in the code, could you comment it a little bit so that I can understand better?

Comment: @JoãoAreias - I've added a couple of comments; look at `cut` (the cut level; start from zero, incremented 1.0 cm until it's possible and printed with fraction) and at `n2` (the number of strips that are longer that `cut`). Sorry but I'm very bad explaining

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I explained very well on my question and there they also don't tell it very well but you can actually get fractions. You see that when you run different test cases, that's why I'm solving it by binary search. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: @JoãoAreias - as you can see, in `(cut + double(ts) / n2)`, the result is expressed as a float number; `cut` is the integer part of the result, `double(ts) / n2` is the remaining (in the range `[0,1[`). But... have you tried my example with the test data?